# Spring.NET Security Framework

Tags: spring.net

In order to learn more about Spring.NET, I bought the book "Spring in Action", which is about the Java version of the framework.

I noticed that the book talks about Spring.Security and how one can manage security/login etc. using this part of the framework.

As I read along, I got quite excited about the features of the security framework, however I soon noticed, that this part of Spring was not ported to .NET? Are there any alternatives / ports which can be used in a similiar way as Acegi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has come up a couple of times so there certainly is interest.  An old project on sourceforge did an automated translation via Microsoft's Java language conversion assistant tool (JLCA) and then some polish to get it too work (I guess).  I've recently looked though that code on the request of a client and didn't really like it because of that automated approach, also since Spring Security 3.0 has been greatly refactored to avoid circular dependencies and provide better internal modularity, I'd restart again a porting effort based on the Spring Security 3.0 code base.  There is a nice blog that explains the structure of Spring 3.0. See http://blog.springsource.com/2009/06/03/spring-security-300m1-released/

So long story short, there are no alternatives now that I am aware of but would be very intersted in having some contributions to start a Spring Extension project www.springsource.org/extensions to port this over.  Please contact me, mark.pollack@springsource.com if you are interested!

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: That is very interesting, thanks a lot you for your answer! What I am wondering: what are people using right now in .NET (web) applications in order to authenticate users e. g. with a mysql database as backend? Session["isLoggedIn"] = true; ?

Comment: hi, I'm also looking for the same solution you were looking for 2 years ago. Did you find the .NET alternative of Spring Security?

Comment: Another 2.5 years, do we have any good security framework for .NET web applications?